# Calculate Annual Leaves for All employees and return more than one column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The following procedure calculates annual  leaves of employees based on the provided empid. First Question: How can I create/modify this procedure to calculate annual leaves for all employees. Second Question:  Return more columns like empname, designation, annual leave balance? please note that i am using sql server 2016 community edition.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spAvailalbeAL](@empID int)
    as
    begin
    declare @StartDate datetime
    declare @totMonths int
    declare @aAnnualLeaves int
    declare @avlAL int

    set @avlAL = (select sum(Availed) from LeaveDetails where empid = @empID AND TypeID=3)

    if ( @avlAL IS NULL)
    begin

        set @StartDate = '2017-07-01'
        set @totMonths = (SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, @StartDate, GETDATE()))
        set @aAnnualLeaves = 2
        set @aAnnualLeaves = (@aAnnualLeaves*@totMonths)
        select @aAnnualLeaves
    end
    else 
        begin
            set @StartDate = '2017-07-01'
            set @totMonths = (SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, @StartDate, GETDATE()))
            set @aAnnualLeaves = 2
            set @aAnnualLeaves = (@aAnnualLeaves*@totMonths)-@avlAL
            select @aAnnualLeaves
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

For showing all employees you can pass `0` or `Null` for `@empid` parameter and then you can create Temporary Table like 
`CREATE TABLE #LeaveDetails(EmpID INT,TotalALAvailed INT)`
then fill the table
`INSERT INTO #LeaveDetails(EmpID,TotalALAvailed) SELECT EmpID,SUM(Availed) FROM LeaveDetails WHERE (EmpID=@EmpID OR @EmpID=0) AND Type=3 GROUP BY EmpID`

You can select all required columns in last Select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
  Create proc [dbo].[spAvailalbeAL]
        as
        begin
        declare @StartDate datetime = '2017-07-01'
        declare @totMonths int 
        declare @aAnnualLeaves int

        set @totMonths = (SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, @StartDate, GETDATE()))
        print @totMonths
        set @aAnnualLeaves = 2
        set @aAnnualLeaves = (@aAnnualLeaves*@totMonths)
        print @aAnnualLeaves

        SELECT distinct e.EMPLOYEE_NAME,e.desg_cd,sum(isnull(ea.Availed,0)) over ( partition by e.EmpID ),@aAnnualLeaves - sum(isnull(ea.Availed,0)) over ( partition by e.EmpID )  as leaves
        from Employee e 
        inner join LeaveDetails ea 
        on e.EMPLOYEE_CD = ea.EMPLOYEE_CD 
        where   DATE > @StartDate
        AND ea.TypeID=3

        end

        -- exec spAvailalbeAL
```

Comment: Dear Anagha, thanks for your reply. This query is working great with little tweaks but it doesn't select those employees who have not availed any annual leave ...

Comment: it tried by using the left join but the result in not grouped i.e. some rows has repeating employees..SELECT e.EmpName,e.Designation, e.DoJ, (isnull(ea.Availed,0)) as AvailedAL,12 - sum(isnull(ea.Availed,0))  as AvailedAL
        from EmpDetails e 
        left join LeaveDetails ea 
        on e.EmpID = ea.EmpID 
        AND ea.TypeID=3
        group by e.EmpName, e.Designation, e.DoJ,ea.Availed

Comment: Try this query:  SELECT distinct e.EmpName,e.Designation, e.DoJ, sum(isnull(ea.Availed,0)) over ( partition by e.EmpID ) as AvailedAL,12 - sum(isnull(ea.Availed,0)) over ( partition by e.EmpID ) as AvailedAL 
 from EmpDetails e left join LeaveDetails ea on e.EmpID = ea.EmpID AND ea.TypeID=3

Comment: Thanks you so much sir ... you are great ... it worked perfectly

Comment: The problem is not completely solved sir, sorry. When I give a condition for a specific date in LeaveDetails table then I don't get values for those employees who have not availed any annual leave yet. i.e. SELECT distinct e.EmpName,e.Designation, e.DoJ, ea.[From], sum(isnull(ea.Availed,0)) over ( partition by e.EmpID ) as AvailedAL,12 - sum(isnull(ea.Availed,0)) over ( partition by e.EmpID ) as AvailableAL from EmpDetails e left join LeaveDetails ea on e.EmpID = ea.EmpID AND ea.TypeID=3 where ea.[From]>='2017-07-01'

Comment: Use this: SELECT distinct e.EmpName,e.Designation, e.DoJ, ea.[From], sum(isnull(ea.Availed,0)) over ( partition by e.EmpID ) as AvailedAL,12 - sum(isnull(ea.Availed,0)) over ( partition by e.EmpID ) as AvailableAL from EmpDetails e left join LeaveDetails ea on e.EmpID = ea.EmpID AND ea.TypeID=3 and ea.[From]>='2017-07-01'

Comment: Thanks Anagha ... it worked ... and I have already marked your answer as accepted solution ..

Comment: When i click on the the ^ button on the left side of your query above it gives me the following message. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. I have clicked there more than once for ' This answer is useful' .. other than this i don't know how to mark a reply as accepted answer ..

Comment: It's pleasure to help you.It's okay.